# Increment non unique field using a sql insert statement

Tags: sql, insert, field, increment

I have three tables **TelNo** , **RefNo** and **Ref_Check_No**. **RefNo** and **Ref_Check_No** has columns **Telephone_Id** and **Entity_Id** respectively along with other columns, while **TelNo** has **Telephone_Id** and **Entity_Id**. What I would like to do is to insert all the records from **Ref_Check_No** into the **RefNo** table. The **TelNo** Table contains the **Telephone_Id** for each **Entity_Id**. All of these columns mentioned are not unique.

The thing is I know how to insert the data from the **Ref_Check_No** table. However, I can't seem to insert the **Telephone_Id** values for each **Entity_Id**. What I would like to do is to retrieve the MAX **Telephone_Id** number per **Entity_Id** from the **TelNo** table and increment it by 1 for each **Entity_Id** in the **RefNo** table using an insert statement. Below is an example of what I would like to achieve in the **RefNo** Table:

```
             **TelNo Table**                  **RefNo Table**
        Telephone_Id   Entity_Id        Telephone_Id    Entity_Id
             1         ABCD               4              ABCD
             2         ABCD               5              ABCD
             3         ABCD               6              ABCD
             89       EFGH               7              ABCD
             90          EFGH              96             EFGH
             95          EFGH              97             EFGH
```

Basically what I want to do is to find the MAX **Telephone_Id** number per **Entity_Id** (ABCD and EFGH) from the 
**TelNo** table and increment it by 1 for each corresponding **Entity_Id** in the **RefNo** table.

Below is the code that I was working on which I can't seem to get right.

```
 INSERT INTO
RefNo
(
Telephone_Id,
Entity_ID,
ContactName
) 
SELECT     
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Ref_Check_No b WHERE(a.Entity_Id = b.Entity_Id) 
    ISNULL ((SELECT MAX(Telephone_Id) AS Telephone_Id FROM TelNo 
    WHERE (Entity_Id = a.Entity_Id)), 0) AS Telephone_Id,

Entity_ID,
ContactName               
FROM         
Ref_Check_No
```

Is there a way to find the MAX **Telephone_Id** number and increment it by 1 for each **Entity_Id** using a correlated sub query while inserting data in the **RefNo** table at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding your example. You want to create one row in RefNo for each record in Ref_Check_No, labelling each with the same Entity_ID and an increasing Telephone_ID?

If that is the case, try this (for MSSQL):

```
INSERT INTO RefNo (Entity_ID, Telephone_ID)    
SELECT r.Entity_ID, 
  t.MAXID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY r.Entity_ID order by r.Telephone_ID) AS Telephone_ID
FROM ref_check_no r
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Entity_ID, Max(Telephone_ID) as MaxID
    FROM TelNo 
      GROUP BY Entity_ID) t 
   ON r.Entity_ID=t.Entity_ID
```

Comment: What I want to do is to insert all the DISTINCT rows and columns from the Ref_Check_No table, labeling each with the same Entity_ID and increasing Telephone_ID. I replaced "order by r.Telephone_ID" with "order by t.MAXID" to get it to work. The code then worked it increased the Telephone_ID for each Entity_ID. However, how can I use this same code to insert all the other columns into RefNo. In other words I want one Insert statement that inserts all distinct records and columns along with incrementing the Telephone_ID. The two other columns to be inserted from Ref_Check_No are FName and SName